# Binary Semaphore not working if release() comes before acquire()

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, binary-semaphore

I am writing a test code where i found if we put `release()` before `acquire()` then Binary Semaphore functionality is broken.

I checked and found more then one thread passes `acquire()` and increase the count to N where N is number of threads and thus contradicting binary semaphore.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

/**
 * Consider an ATM cubicle with 1 ATM, Semaphore can make sure only 1 person
 * can access simultaneously.
 * 
 * Here if relese() comes before then this binary semaphore is not working.
 */
public class SemaphoreTest {

    // max 4 people
    static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Total available Semaphore permits : " + semaphore.availablePermits());

        MyATMThread t1 = new MyATMThread("A",semaphore);
        t1.start();

        MyATMThread t2 = new MyATMThread("B",semaphore);
        t2.start();

        MyATMThread t3 = new MyATMThread("C",semaphore);
        t3.start();

        MyATMThread t4 = new MyATMThread("D",semaphore);
        t4.start();

        MyATMThread t5 = new MyATMThread("E",semaphore);
        t5.start();

        MyATMThread t6 = new MyATMThread("F",semaphore);
        t6.start();

    }
}

class MyATMThread extends Thread {

    String name = "";
    Semaphore semaphore = null;

    MyATMThread(String name,Semaphore s) {
        this.name = name;
        this.semaphore=s;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            System.out.println(name + " : acquiring lock...");
            System.out.println(name + " : available Semaphore permits now: " + semaphore.availablePermits());
            semaphore.release();
            semaphore.acquire();
            System.out.println(name + " : got the permit!");

            try {

                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

                    System.out.println(name + " : is performing operation " + i + ", available Semaphore permits : "
                            + semaphore.availablePermits());

                    // sleep 1 second
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                }

            } finally {

                // calling release() after a successful acquire()
                System.out.println(name + " : releasing lock...");
                semaphore.release();
                System.out.println(name + " : available Semaphore permits now: " + semaphore.availablePermits());

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Can some one explain this behavior ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're writing broken code (at least by your expectations) by releasing (increasing permits) before acquiring. This is perfectly valid, but if you intend to have a single permit, you shouldn't be increasing them by calling `release()` before `acquire()`.

`Semaphore` allows you to increase the permits beyond what was given as the initial amount. This can be used for example throttling. Worker threads will do `acquire()/release()` and a throttler will decrease/increase permits depending on some logic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, really want to know why developers of semaphore allows this as releasing lock before acquiring will always results in erroneous state.

Comment: There's nothing erroneous about increasing permits. Your code results in erroneous state, but that's not the semaphore's fault. You chose to call `release()` before `acquire()`.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman , could you please give a one liner example where we can use release() before acquire so that i can understand this behavior more accurately.

Comment: You shouldn't in normal cases. I gave an example where a third party controls the amount of permits, but usually you would use the standard correct pattern.

Comment: In addition the code releases the Semaphore 2 times in each Thread and acquires it only once, which is also broken. Setting a semaphore initially to 0 and start with releasing is perfectly valid for usecases that require it, e.g. to implement some kind of ManualResetEvent: Releasing the Semaphore will allow an acquiring thread to proceed.

Comment: The classic example is a thread pool where a number of threads are waiting on an empty semaphore for work to arrive on a queue.  10 threads might turn up and post 10 work requests to the queue, each one release-ing a unit to the semaphore, (whose count it then 10).  The work threads then acquire the units and dequeue work, lowering the count, until all the work is done, the count is 0 again and the worker threads are waiting on the semaphore once more : release before acquire.

Comment: In fact, any producer-consumer queue that uses a semaphore to count the entries.  At creation time,. such a semaphore is initialized to 0 since the new queue is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The release() method is used to increment permits since, from the docs:

> There is no requirement that a thread that releases a permit must 
>   have acquired that permit by calling acquire.  Correct usage of a
>   semaphore is established by programming convention in the application.

In other words:

semaphore.release(10), Will add 10 more permits to current permits

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `release()` as "creating" another permit if that thread had not previously acquired a permit from that `Semaphore`.